# Nano can't get reply from ENC28J60 Ethernet Shield

Tags: arduino-nano, spi, shields, ethernet-shield

My Arduino Nano can't get a reply from my new ENC28J60 Ethernet Shield - I can't get any library examples to work. Using the UIPEthernet lib, and running the EchoServer example with logging turned up, I get:

```
ENC28J60::init DEBUG:csPin = 10
ENC28J60::init DEBUG:miso = 12
ENC28J60::init DEBUG:mosi = 11
ENC28J60::init DEBUG:sck = 13
ENC28J60::init DEBUG:Use Native hardware SPI
Enc28J60Network::writeOp(uint8_t op, uint8_t address, uint8_t data) DEBUG_V3:Function started
ENC28J60::init DEBUG_V3:Before readOp(ENC28J60_READ_CTRL_REG, ESTAT)
Enc28J60Network::readOp(uint8_t op, uint8_t address) DEBUG_V3:Function started
...
```

so it gets nicely into the Enc28J60Network::init function. But shortly after, it does a phyWrite, tries to read a response, and then times out.

```
ENC28J60::init DEBUG_V3:Before phyWrite(PHCON2, PHCON2_HDLDIS)
Enc28J60Network::phyWrite(uint8_t address, uint16_t data) DEBUG_V3:Function started
... lots of attempts to read
Enc28J60Network::phyWrite ERROR:TIMEOUT !!
```

And then it all starts to fail, and it never gets better. I tried the EtherCard lib, too, and it fails in a similar way.

I put the scope on the SPI pins, and I see reasonable stuff: activity on SCK and MOSI, nothing on MISO, and the SS (pin 10) switching ok - and the shield claims to use pin 10 (I briefly tried pin 8 as I flailed in confusion, but no luck there either).

So at this point, either I'm misunderstanding something, or the shield is DOA.

*Update*: Earlier, I strongly suspected the SCK line because it showed a very poor signal on my scope. But it turned out to be poor grounding on the scope probe, and the signal  was actually fine, a red herring. Thanks to @Majenko for drawing my attention to it.

*Update 2*: After getting no SPI response from the shield under any circumstances, my working hypothesis is that it was DOA. I've gone back to my UNO with W5100: all working fine. I have ordered more Nano ethernet shields, to arrive in a week or two, so I'll try with those, and provide updates/answers then.

Comment: How much bandwidth does your scope have? That looks awfully low resolution, and the kind of output I'd expect on a scope with not enough bandwidth to display the waveform correctly.

Comment: is ethernet cable connected?

Comment: @Majenko good point - and thanks for the pointer. I'd not earthed the scope probe  properly, so fixed, and the SCK line looks perfectly fine now. D'oh, beginner's mistake. I'll edit it out of the question.

Comment: @Juraj yes, all connected - and I get a little green light on the shield and on the hub, so I think it's all good there.

Comment: How much current can your 3.3V supply to the ENC28J60 Ethernet Shield? The data sheet says it uses 120mA when it's "Active, not transmitting Ethernet packets". Up to 180mA is required when it's "Transmitting Ethernet packets".

Comment: @VE7JRO oh I never thought of that... I've spent a whole day trying to .... :-) ok, checking now ...

Comment: @VE7JRO Your suggestion seems to be backed up by this discussion: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=452822.0 ... I couldn't find anything much to test: my nano's 3.3V pin is stable, but that might be because the shield isn't drawing power when it sees the supply so weak. I'm now building an independent 3.3V supply...

Comment: @VE7JRO I've just hooked a 3.3V 2A supply up to the Nano's 3.3V line to give it more juice - no change. I think it's ok to just wire the power straight up to it, even though the 3.3V line is nominally an output (am I right?); I believe I'll definitely need to augment it anyway, but I'm starting to feel the shield is DOA. I wonder if running it with weak power killed it....? seems a bit feeble if it did.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97820/discussion-on-question-by-susanw-nano-cant-get-reply-from-enc28j60-ethernet-shi).

Comment: Perhaps this could bring some solution. https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/477142

Comment: @Riad what happened to your nice answer?

Comment: @Riad My shield matches the one on that forum and has the miscreant connection. I haven't tried fixing it because it's hard and I have other shields now. But I have high confidence that this is the answer. If you want to take credit, please write an answer; otherwise I shall do so myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Riad, who posted this as a comment. The problem appears to be a design fault in the "DK ectronics" V1.0 Ethernet Shield.

> Perhaps this could bring some solution. https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/477142

The site is in German, so here's a brief translation of the key parts:

> I bought an ENC28J60 for the Arduino Nano, but it does not respond from the programmed IP.
>
> The shield has "NANO Ethernet Shield V1.0 DK ectronics" inscribed on the underside (spelling error in the original). There
>   there is a via on the bottom between pins D11 and D12,
>   missing from a (different) working shield. This via connects D12 line to GND from the AMS1117 on the top (easy to check D12 to GND with a multimeter). If that's the case with your shield, then this is the problem: we just have to cut out the via connection. I have
>   Do this with a 1mm drill by placing the top copper layer in the
>   via very gently (really gently!) Mill it away. If you drill too deep, you break the D12 connection completely and must possibly
>   solder on a new wire. Keep checking D12 and GND for continuity to see whether you've milled away enough. Work really carefully!
>
> After I did that, and tried the TCP Server example in the UIPEthernet
>   library on the Arduino, the shield was reachable.
>
> -- Christoph K

I haven't yet tried to make the changes described above, because they are fiddly and I have a new batch of working shields. But my device is exactly as described by Christoph and his photos, and the fault description matches mine.

Answer (score 2):

The ENC28j60 shield for Nano has reset of the ENC28j60 chip on the pin 7 of the shield/Nano. Try to set the pin 7 HIGH.

Comment: If this solves it, it would be hilarious... ok, will try it at the weekend - alas I'm away atm. So, I just have to add: `pinMode(7, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, HIGH);` on setup? Hmm, I wonder why the UIP/EtherCard library examples don't have this. Perhaps the reset is non-standard, or there's a (too) weak pull-up?

Comment: @SusanW, did it help?

Comment: no it didn't, I'm afraid - I added `pinMode(7, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, LOW); delay(1000); pinMode(7, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(7, HIGH);` just to give it the best chance possible, but it still times-out on read and the MISO line is silent. Which is annoying, because what you suggested would be the perfect answer - and on reading around, it appears the pin-7 reset is an under-publicised feature. Anyway, I've ordered some more shields which should arrive any day, so I'll be able to eliminate board failure as a factor. I'll keep you posted... Thanks!

Comment: @SusanW, do not reset it. only set the pin HIGH. do it as first in setup().

Comment: Yep, I tried that first ....

Comment: Ok, new shields turned up - and worked first time. We have pings and TCP. And ironically, it works even without me setting pin-7 high. The other board must be dead. Hmm ... would you like to add that as an "alternative explanation" to your answer, or something, then I can mark this as the accepted answer. (I could add/accept an answer myself saying "Board was dead", but that would hide your more useful answer!)

Comment: @SusanW, at least you know you can not use the pin 7 or you must bend it on shield to use it on Nano. Or you can use it as reset of the shield, but I didn't find it useful with module I have.

Comment: It works if pin 7 is input on Nano, because the reset pin of the ENC28j60 has a pull-up.

Comment: I've written up an answer based on Riad's link about faulty ethernet shields, which matches the problem I had. But I feel bad because your answer is informed and helpful. If there's a better way to get the *"Susan bought a rubbish board off eBay"* explanation out there, do let me know! Thanks.